# Find specific word between tag start and end

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find a word `this` within `<template>` and `</template>`:

I tried `<template>([this])*?<\/template>` but it doesn't seem to work.

https://regex101.com/r/VmGESa/1

Comment: What do you mean by "find"? Do you simply wish to determine if `"this"` is present between the markers or do you want its location (offset) as well (if present)? What about `"thistle"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is matching strings that

- are starting with `<template>`,
- followed by an arbitrary combination of the characters `t`, `h`, `i` or `s` with arbitrary length, e.g., `thssiththissiththhtht` would be matched by `([this])*`,
- are ending with `</template>`,

Does this solution work for you?

```
<template>(?:.|\n|\r)*(this)(?:.|\n|\r)*<\/template>
```

`.*` matches an arbitrary number of arbitrary characters, except for new lines. So, I added `\n` and `\r` with the OR operator `|`. `(?:...)` means, it's a non-capturing group, i.e., when asking for groups, this group won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the multiline `m` flag and `.` doesn't match linebreaks so you have to account for that.

E.g.

`<template>(?:.|\r|\n)*?(this)(?:.|\r|\n)*?<\/template>`

https://regex101.com/r/krkP9d/1